# Linking mysql with google's bigquery

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've a legacy ecommerce application with `nodejs` & `mysql`. Now I want to add this mysql data to bigquery dataset.

How should I link / connect both of them together?

**Ways might work**

- Export data to csv and import into bigquery.
- Add the data to Bigquery
- while adding it to `mysql`.
- Stream inserts
- Create a job that will fetch and insert into bigquery.

**Goals to achieve**

- `mysql` and `bigquery` should be in sync, (latency of 15-30 minutes doesn't matter),
- Should have old data as well as new data, don't want to reupload again and again, application / tools should link them together
- Should able to add logs data as well, from nodejs 'console.log'

I want to know, 
What could be a better approch to integrated them flawlessly?
How should I do this?

Comment: If you're open to a hands-off but most likely paid solution, there are [BigQuery partners](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/) who specialize in data replication.

Comment: Isn't there way to do without 3rd party (paid services). I want to try it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. Maybe the easiest of them is to export a CSV and upload it to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Make a Cloud Function, which will be triggered when the file is uploaded to the bucket and it will do the upload of data to the BigQuery for us. Here are the steps that should be taken:

1. Create [new dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quickstart-web-ui#create_a_dataset) and [table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#create-table) in BigQuery
2. Make a script on your site to export the new data to a CSV file and upload it to the bucket:

   Uploading to the bucket:

   ```
   // Imports the Google Cloud client library
   const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage'); 
   // Creates a client
   const storage = new Storage();
   storage
     .bucket(bucketName)
     .upload(filename)
     .then(() => {
       console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.error('ERROR:', err);
     });
   ```
3. [Create a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console#create_a_function) triggered by the bucket which will be triggered on each upload of the CSV file, connect to the BigQuery and [load data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery-load-table-gcs-csv-create-code_samples) into the table.

   Instantiates clients:

   ```
   const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
   const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

   const bigquery = new BigQuery({
     projectId: projectId,
   });

   const storage = new Storage({
     projectId: projectId,
   });
   ```

   Configure the load job based on your schema:

   ```
   const metadata = {
     sourceFormat: 'CSV',
     skipLeadingRows: 1,
     schema: {
       fields: [
         {name: 'column1', type: 'STRING'},
         {name: 'column2', type: 'STRING'},
       ],
     },
   };
   ```

   Load data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table:

   ```
   bigquery
     .dataset(datasetId)
     .table(tableId)
     .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata)
     .then(results => {
       const job = results[0];

       // load() waits for the job to finish
       assert.equal(job.status.state, 'DONE');
       console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);

       // Check the job's status for errors
       const errors = job.status.errors;
       if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
         throw errors;
       }
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.error('ERROR:', err);
     });
   ```

Comment: This is lot more work, export data, upload to cloud. instead of uploading to csv to cloude storage, one can upload directly to bigquery.

Comment: But again this manual process, 
what if previously data gets updated in mysql. or it is like updating whole database to bigquery again and again.

Comment: @AnkitBalyan The given solution do the upload automatically if you do, for example, cron task on your site. 
BigQuery is not designed to be used as a database. It's purpose is to be used as a data warehouse, where it can be analyzed through queries.